# log4j tomcat access denied

Tags: tomcat, log4j

We are running into and issue with log4j and tomcat.  We receive an access denied message when trying to rename the file but checking the permissions everything looks fine.  Any ideas this would not work?

```
2016-07-06 20:00:35,422 Log4j2-AsyncLoggerConfig-2 ERROR Unable to rename file /var/log/tomcat/logs/log.log to /log-2016-07-06-16-1.log - Permission denied
```

**permissions**

```
drwxr-xr-x.  3 tomcat tomcat 8.0K Jul  7 16:57 tomcat
drwxr-xr-x.  2 tomcat tomcat 4.0K Jul  5 15:31 logs
```

**log4j config**

```
    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="/var/log/tomcat/logs/log.log" append="true"
                 filePattern="log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, was trying to write to `/` since I didn't have the apth in the `filePattern` directive.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/var/log/tomcat/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${log-path}/log.log" append="true"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to explain whats different and how this answers the question